# User defined Mysql Functions in where condition Fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

I have created Mysql function which gives result integer or NULL. It works fine for all values. If use this function in simple query it aslo works as expected like following query :

```
select distinct(hsd.hotel_id) 
from hotel_season_detail hsd 
where '2019-04-26' BETWEEN hsd.season_fromdate and hsd.season_todate and hsd.stop_sale >'2019-04-26' and getHotelMarkupManagementId(hsd.id,'AFG') is NOT NULL
```

`getHotelMarkupManagementId()` is user defined mysql function. As above query return two hotel ids which is already exist in hotel table.

But when this query added as subquery like

```
select * from hotel_service 
where id in 
(select distinct(hsd.hotel_id) 
from hotel_season_detail hsd where '2019-04-26' BETWEEN hsd.season_fromdate and hsd.season_todate and hsd.stop_sale >'2019-04-26' and getHotelMarkupManagementId(hsd.id,'AFG') 
is NOT NULL)
```

It gives Wrong result. It does not work as expected.
`select * from hotel_service where id in (125,126)` gives result and subquery also gives id 125 and 126 as result if run individually. but when added as subquery it fails

Should this behavior due to `mysql function` in `IN` clause? Please Suggest.

Comment: In what way does it give the wrong result?

Comment: First query returns two hotel_id 125,126 but when placed  under `IN` like in second query does not give any result. But when placed that values statically like `id IN (125,126)` then it gives result

Comment: Using the function in the subquery should not affect that. You should be able to verify that by removing the function from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: the `hotel_service.id` is the `hotel_season_detail.hotel_id`? not `hotel_service.hotel_id`? just to make sure the relationship is correct. the query looks fine and the functions should work as expected.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch `hotel_service` has multiple `hotel_season` with `hotel_id` as foreign key

Comment: Is the `id` column of table `hotel_service` a hotel ID or the ID of a hotel service? Please show your table columns of `hotel_service` and `hotel_season_detail`.

Comment: @Nick Already try with this but no success. and Interestingly subquery giving me result if run individually

Comment: @SebastianBrosch It's `id`

Comment: `select * from hotel_service where id in (125,126) `gives result and subquery also gives id 125 and 126 as result if run individually. but when added as subquery it fails

Comment: define "fail". Is there an error or you just get wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an issue in Mysql when working with function because if same second query condition divided into two subqueries then My problem gets solved.

```
select * from hotel_service where id in (select distinct(hsd.hotel_id) from hotel_season_detail hsd where '2019-04-26' BETWEEN hsd.season_fromdate and hsd.season_todate and hsd.stop_sale >'2019-04-26') and id in (select distinct(hsd.hotel_id) from hotel_season_detail hsd where getHotelMarkupManagementId(hsd.id,'AFG') is not NULL)
```

I have separated MySQL function in different subquery but combine same condition then not gives proper result. So i suggest use function of mysql different from other conditions, If conditions were `BETWEEN` OR `>` Operator.